# XPath loop through a <ul> of <li> elements and extract text from a span and nested span in python

Tags: python, xpath

I have seen variations of this question but not an answer that I can manipulate to get working. I'm trying to figure out how to loop through a list of text and extract two separate values from each list item using XPath. I can do it for a single item but I'm stuck on how to do it in a loop.
Here is an example snippet of what I'm working with

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="main content">
      <span class="nested content">123</span>abc
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="main content">
      <span class="nested content">456</span>def
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="main content">
      <span class="nested content">789</span>ghi
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is access each `<li>`, but then extract the text from the span with class "main content" separately from the span with class "nested content".  I can try to explain more if needed but I think this gets my question across.

Comment: Which tool you use? Share your current code

Comment: scrapy to go through webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lxml package to get a tree from the string with the following:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(html_string)
```

Then you can access an xpath by using .xpath() like this:

```
all_text = tree.xpath("normalize-space(//li/span)")
nested_text = tree.xpath("normalize-space(//li/span/span)")
```

The normalize-space() function returns all of the text. Using the above two lines you can get the inner text and then the entire text, and then you can remove the inner from entire text with

```
outer_text = all_text.replace(nested_text, '')
```

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if it doesn't work for what you are asking.

(Disclaimer: The xpaths above only work for the example you shared. Obviously they might need to change if that is only a subset of the html you are accessing)

Comment: Yes this worked exactly the way I needed it to. Thanks!